# First hazelcast node is shutting down instead of becoming master

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp, hazelcast, distributed-cache

I am trying to form a cluster using tcp/ip discovery. I am unable to understand as to why the first node is not being chosen as master. There are no other nodes in the cluster. And the error logs are not self explanatory.

Debug logs :

```
2020-10-27 05:31:46 DEBUG com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Setting master address to null
2020-10-27 05:31:46 DEBUG com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] PostJoin master: null, isMaster: false
2020-10-27 05:31:46 ERROR com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Could not join cluster. Shutting down now!
2020-10-27 05:31:46 INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] [192.168.10.31]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2020-10-27 05:31:46 WARN  com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Terminating forcefully...
2020-10-27 05:31:46 DEBUG com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Setting master address to null
2020-10-27 05:31:46 INFO  com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Shutting down connection manager...
```

Hazelcast version : 3.12

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
  <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Hazelcast config :

```
String hazelcastClusterMemberOne = 192.168.10.*
Config config = new Config();
        NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();
        JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();
        join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember(hazelcastClusterMemberOne)
                .setEnabled(true);

        HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Error Logs :

```
2020-10-27 05:31:46 [main] ERROR com.hazelcast.instance.Node com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Could not join cluster. Shutting down now!
2020-10-27 05:31:46 [main] INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] [192.168.10.31]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
2020-10-27 05:31:46 [main] WARN  com.hazelcast.instance.Node com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Terminating forcefully...
2020-10-27 05:31:46 [main] INFO  com.hazelcast.instance.Node com.hazelcast.instance.Node:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] Shutting down connection manager...
```

**EDIT :**
This is happening on the server which is hosted on AWS cloud, but the above config works fine on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing from a wildcard to an explicit IP address.

Ie.
Not

```
getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.10.*")
                .setEnabled(true);
```

but

```
getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.10.1")
                .setEnabled(true);
```

Or if you need several possibilities, list them explicitly

```
getTcpIpConfig().addMember("192.168.10.1")
                .addMember("192.168.10.2")
                .addMember("192.168.10.3")
                .setEnabled(true);
```

*UPDATED BELOW*

`TcpIpConfig` wasn't intended for use with a large range of possibilities. Wwildcard is not implemented for this field. You could list all 256 possibilities, or submit a PR implementing wildcard. Either way it's 256 port to probe, which will be on the slow side.

If you know the address of the first node at runtime, you could pass this into the others as a property.

If you don't, then one of the other discovery mechanisms is probably going to be a better choice.

Note also, `TcpIpConfig` is just the specification for discovery mechanism, not the communication mechanism once discovered. Performance of member to member communication is unrelated to the choice of discovery mechanism.

*UPDATED 2 BELOW*
The above answer is incorrect, having now tried it with 3.12.0, wildcard is implemented.

Comment: The reason why i have given wildcard is the IP addresses of the members are not static and they might vary from 0 - 255

Comment: Understood, have updated my answer with some more detail.

Comment: I was under the impression that wildcard was supported , thats what threw me off! Thanks! But any idea why the wildcard worked in my local setup ?

Comment: Hi, yes it seems it is, having actually tried it. So that's not the issue. I see that you're on AWS, so perhaps the [AWS Discovery Plugin](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws) will be the way forward. However, it would still be useful to know what the cause of the error is on AWS. Do you have more logs you can share ?  If you are attempting a range of IP addresses, it's possible you are finding someone else's cluster and being rejected from connecting to it.

Comment: In the logs i see the node sending master question to all the ips in the member list. Some ips getting back listed. There is the following error when the node claims to be the master : `2020-10-27 05:31:46 DEBUG com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner:49 - [192.168.10.31]:5701 [dev] [3.12] com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not sent to -> [192.168.10.111]:5703 over null` After this , the master address is set as null and the node shuts down.

Comment: So there is another node already running on 192.168.1.111 when your first one starts on 192.168.10.31 ? Also, that other node is on port 5703, so there could be three other nodes 192.168.1.111:5701, 192.168.1.111:5702 & 192.168.1.111:5703. Is 192.168.1.111 one of your machines ?

Comment: No , there are no other nodes running. Only 192.168.10.31 is running and I try to start my node on this machine.

Comment: Can you post the full log from your machine on 192.168.10.31 please ?

Comment: There are just too many logs to post here. It's alright , thanks a lot for your help! I ended up going with passing the first node's address to the member list!